# How do I do SELECT on multiple colums(ex. 2)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, having

```
SELECT DName
FROM drugs
WHERE DID IN 
(
    SELECT DID,SID
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY TotalCost
    HAVING SID = 1 AND TotalCost > 100
)
```

Doing such a query inside brackets will give me a result with 2 columns that I need to select results from one of them. In order to use SID in `HAVING` clause, I need to include it in `SELECT` operator inside brackets and that's why I am getting 2 columns as a result.

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what your query needs to do and also include schema information if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 columns in an IN statement.
You can just remove the SID from the select and only use it in the HAVING. You don't actually need to retrieve the data and your IN clause will work.

Comment: Both of them are wrong. I have tried that already and given result was:
ERROR 1054: Unknown column "SID" in "having clause"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then you want something like this:

```
SELECT DName
FROM drugs
WHERE (DID, SID) IN 
(
    //Subquery
)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? it will fail for multiple reasons: 1. you can't use in like that. 2. the inner query is wrong since it has columns in the select clause that does not appear on the group by clause or in an aggregating function.

Comment: @ZoharPeled 1. We can use in like that. 2. Just copied the inner query from question. Will modify it. Thanks

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that! I'm an sql server guy myself, and it will fail on sql server. didn't know that you can use IN for multiple column in MySql. I stand corrected.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Mysql will not throw any error if non aggregated select columns are not included in group by.

Comment: I've tried once more but as Zohar said, it's not possible to do IN on multiple columns, sorry.

Comment: Turns out MySql does some pretty messed up stuff that is not compliant  with ANSI-SQL, such as allowing columns to be in the select clause when they are not in the group by clause and allowing the in operator to work on multiple columns. from an sql server guy point of view this is bizarre to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated. Sorry i have been deleted my previous answer. And thanks to ZoharPeled for reminding that my previous answer's wrong.

If I understood your question, This should works for you :

```
SELECT DName
FROM drugs
WHERE DID IN (
    SELECT DID FROM(
        SELECT DID,SID,TotalCost
        FROM transactions
        GROUP BY TotalCost
        HAVING SID = 1 AND TotalCost > 100
    ) AS T
)
```

Comment: the inner query is wrong since it has columns in the select clause that does not appear on the group by clause or in an aggregating function.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ah yes, I didn't notice it. Just copied from op question. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) in the following way:

```
SELECT DName
FROM drugs
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM transactions
    WHERE SID = 1 
    AND TotalCost > 100
    AND ( 
       drugs.DID = transactions.SID
       OR drugs.DID = transactions.DID
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few answers there - but I'll throw an alternative option into the ring:

```
select DName
  from drugs d
 inner join (
                SELECT DID
                  FROM transactions
                 WHERE SID = 1 
                   AND TotalCost > 100
             ) tx on d.Did =tx.Did
```

I think (and I'm open to correction here) that if you use something like...

```
  select *
    from table
   where EXISTS in ( // some subquery )
```

... the subquery in the `EXISTS` clause must be run for *each* row found in `table`. With an inner join approach, the RDBMS will execute the sql for the inline table once and then hold the results in memory to join back to the other table. For small tables this is fine - but for larger tables there could be a significant performance hit.